# Transparent background not showing in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

i'm trying to set the background `transparent` as

```
.dropdown dd ul li {
    background-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.7);
```

its working fine in all browsers except `IE`, in IE it just shows the white background.

Regards.

Comment: Can't work because it isn't supported, see http://css-tricks.com/2151-rgba-browser-support/

Comment: In simple words <IE8 (not sure about IE 8) does not support `rgba(...);`.

Comment: @Niko tnx for a gr8 link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think IE has a [problem](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/) with rgba. You might want to check out the post.

Answer (score 1):

IE browsers before IE9 do not support RGBA colors. The "usual" way to solve that would be to use a PNG image with opacity (IE7+). Quick Google search also revealed [this hack](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/).